# application layer protocol for streaming YouTube (windows/unix)

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

I am writing a desktop application (web wrapper) that might require streaming youtube video.
Which application layer protocol is best suited for streaming YouTube videos? Do Chrome, Firefox, and Safari use the same application layer protocol for streaming YouTube videos?

Comment: What the heck is a _"web wrapper"_? Also what programming language (C++? Java? C#?).. Use the [**`edit`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46683924/edit) button (under your tags) to add any extra info you think might help to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you're using some web component of your programming language then just point it towards a Youtube video url. This displays full video page within your app.

```
webComponent.load("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx");
```

(2) If you want just the Youtube player only (without comments and side thumbnails. etc) then :

Replace:  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx`

With: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx`

(3) If you want the video file (without Youtube player) to display through your own player:

Look at Yoututue API for your language : **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/** 
(or else use a library like **Youtube-DL** to get MP4 files returned into your app).